# update table with join without PK in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

```
UPDATE
  (
    SELECT
      a.COL1
    FROM
      TABLE1 a,
      TABLE2 b,
      TABLE3 c
    WHERE
      a.name = b.name
      c.ccol = b.ccol AND
      AND b.col1 = 'anyvalue'
      AND a.col2 = 'anothervalue'
  ) u
SET
  u.COL1 = 'VALUE'
```

This query does not work, since TABLE1 does not contains PK. How to write such a query ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should achieve what it looks like you are trying to achieve above:

```
UPDATE  TABLE1
SET     COL1 = 'VALUE'
WHERE   EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    TABLE2 B
                    INNER JOIN TABLE3 C
                        ON B.Ccol = C.Ccol
            WHERE   b.Name = Table1.Name
            AND     b.Col1 = 'AnyValue'
            AND     c.Col1 = 'AnotherValue'
        )
```

Comment: SQL update of OP is valid syntax in Oracle. And yes, this query will fail if TABLE1 does not contains primary key

Comment: @Anton I've removed the part about updating a subquery from the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've never worked in oracle, but try something like this. Not having a pk shouldn't be an issue, as long as your joins & where statements are correct.

**This is the SQL equivalent of what you're asking for**

```
UPDATE u
  SET  u.COL1 = 'VALUE'
  FROM Table1 AS u
  INNER JOIN Table2 AS b ON u.name  = b.name 
  INNER JOIN Table3 AS c ON c.ccol  = b.ccol 
 WHERE b.col1 = 'anyvalue'  AND u.col2 = 'anothervalue'
```

Comment: You can't do UPDATE FROM ... JOIN in Oracle... :)

Comment: ah thank you!  :), now i know as well. i did notice his syntax was a bit strange, thought i could take a stab at answering.